# COALESCE types jsonb and boolean cannot be matched

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

I have next part of query:

```
 'goals', COALESCE(
          json_object_agg(log.type, COALESCE(log.data, TRUE)) FILTER (WHERE log.type IS NOT NULL),
          '{}'
        )
```

and I am getting next error:

```
ERROR:  COALESCE types jsonb and boolean cannot be matched
LINE 30: ...ject_agg(log.type, COALESCE(log.data, TRUE)) FIL...
                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error with the query comes here:

```
coalesce(log.data, true)
```

Both operands of `coalesce()` must have the same datatype. It looks like `data` is `json`, so it mismatches against boolean value `true`.

Probably, you want to cast the boolean to a json text:

```
coalesce(log.data, 'true'::json)
```

This should also work:

```
coalesce(log.data, 'true')
```

Comment: after cast, I am getting almost the same error:
COALESCE types jsonb and text cannot be matched.
It should be just 'true', without cats :)